# Getting last element of an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmldocument

let say i have the following xml file

```
<Users>
 <User>
  <Name>David</Name>
  <Date>9/30/2012 10:52:00 PM</Date>
 </User>
 <User>
  <Name>David</Name>
  <Date>9/30/2012 11:02:05 PM</Date>
 </User>
 <User>
  <Name>David</Name>
  <Date>9/30/2012 11:52:00 PM</Date>
 </User>
 <User>
 <Name>Michelle</Name>
 <Date>9/30/2012 11:02:13 PM</Date>
 </User>
 <User>
  <Name>Michelle</Name>
  <Date>9/30/2012 11:02:54 PM</Date>
 </User>
</Users>
```

I will like to read the last date of David and put it on a string in my C# program, in this case it will be "9/30/2012 11:52:00 PM" I have the following code which is suppose to read the date of a particular User, but it is not working

```
       public void readLastDate(string name)
        {      
        string filePaths = "logins.xml";
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(filePaths);

        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("searching",name);
        XmlNodeList tests = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Users[Name =/*/@searching]/User");
        foreach (XmlNode test in tests)
        {
            string myDate = test.SelectSingleNode("LoginDate").InnerText;
            InfoBox.Items.Add("Last  Date:" + myDate);

        }
```

Also, how would i handle an error if i want to read a date of a user that is not in the xml file.
        }

Comment: Are you tied to XmlDocument? LINQ to XML makes all of this rather simpler - personally I'm not a fan of XPath, although if you're comfortable with it, there's be less reason to switch to LINQ to XML...

Comment: im not really familiar with linq to xml, how would i do all this in linq to xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML, example is how to read the *last date* of *David*

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("logins.xml");

var userElements = xDoc.Descendants("User")
    .Where(x => x.Element("Name").Value == "David")
    .ToList();

if (userElements.Any())
{
    string lastDate = userElements.Select(x => 
                                       DateTime.Parse(x.Element("Date").Value))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
        .First()
        .ToString();
}
```

More information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: thanks, how would i handle an error if a search for a user that is not in the xml file?

Comment: Im getting this error:Error 2 Non-invocable member 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>.HasValue' cannot be used like a method

Answer (score 2):

In XPath, `(/Users/User[Name = 'David'])[position() = last()]`

However, first you must fix the errors in your XML file ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I too would use Linq-to-XML. I think my approach is pretty clean.

```
var result =
    XDocument
        .Load(fileName)
        .Element("Users")
        .Elements("User")
        .Where(xe => xe.Element("Name").Value == "David")
        .Select(xe => DateTime.Parse(xe.Element("Date").Value))
        .OrderByDescending(d => d)
        .FirstOrDefault();

if (result == default(DateTime))
{
    /* no value */
}
```